# OpenLayers displaying Polygon with Icon style

Tags: polygon, openlayers, style, react

I was working on a React project with an OpenLayers map and I was having problems with showing Polygons on the map. When the map is too zoomed out, the Polygons would be to small to see them. So then I tried to display them as pin Icons. By adding a Icon style to the Vector style and only displaying that Vector at a certain zoom level. But I can't get the pin Icons to show on the map.

This is the function where I add the new layer to the map. Note that I have disabled the maxZoom property in the Vector just for testing purposes. So that the Icons should be visible at all zoom levels. But when I get everything working, this would be undone.

```
import PinIcon from "../../assets/icon.png";

class Map{

...

addUsersPlotBoundriesLayer(newFeatures) {
    if (newFeatures.length > 0) {
      let vectorSource = new VectorSource({
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        minScale: 15000000,
        strategy: bboxStrategy,
      });
      newFeatures.forEach((newFeature) => {
        let feature = new Feature({
          geometry: new Polygon([newFeature.geometry]),
        });
        vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
      });
      let iconStyle = new Style({
        image: new Icon({
          anchor: [0.5, 46],
          anchorXUnits: "fraction",
          anchorYUnits: "pixels",
          src: PinIcon,
        }),
      });
      let vector = new Vector({
        //maxZoom: 13,
        source: vectorSource,
        style: iconStyle,
      });
      vector.setZIndex(10);
      vector.set("name", "plotUserBoundriesLayer");
      this.map.addLayer(vector);
    }
  }

...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Icons are only displayed for Point or MultiPoint geometry.  To display Icons for Polygons the style must include a geometry function which returns a Point or MultiPoint (you would usually use the label points)

```
  let iconStyle = new Style({
    geometry: function(feature) {
      let geometry = feature.getGeometry();
      let geometryType = geometry.getType();
      return (
          geometryType == 'Polygon' ? geometry.getInteriorPoint() :
          geometryType == 'MultiPolygon' ? geometry.getInteriorPoints() :
          geometry
      );
    },
    image: new Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: "fraction",
      anchorYUnits: "pixels",
      src: PinIcon,
    }),
  });
```

Comment: little addon: if you want to style the polygons and add the marker on top of it you can add multiple styles and put them in an array, see example here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/polygon-styles.html

Answer (score 0):

Reviving this post as Mike's answer assigns icons to every polygon in a Multipolygon geometry, which wasn't what I hoped for.

To get a single center coordinate of a Multipolygon, this code worked for me:

```
  let iconStyle = new Style({
    geometry: function(feature) {
        let geometry: Geometry = feature.getGeometry();
        let geometryType: string = geometry.getType();

        if (geometryType == 'MultiPolygon'){
            const multiPoint = geometry.getInteriorPoints();
            const center = getCenter(multiPoint.getExtent());
            multiPoint.setCoordinates([center], "XY");
            return multiPoint;
        } else if (geometryType == 'Polygon'){
            return geometry!.getInteriorPoint();
        } else {
            return geometry;
        }
    },
    image: new Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: "fraction",
      anchorYUnits: "pixels",
      src: PinIcon,
    }),
  });
```